# Error audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit`cuando intento instalar algunos paquetes con NPM?

Tags: npm, babeljs

primero intente reintalar `npm` y lo desistale y lo instale de nuevo con el comando de `npm`.

y instale de nuevo los siguientes los siguientes paquetes antes de instalar estos:

```
$ npm init -y

$ npm i -g babel@5.8.23

$ npm i -D babel-core@5.8.25

$ npm i -D babel-plugin-angular2-annotations@2.0.1
```

pero cuando intente instalar el ultimo comando obtengo el siguiente 
  error:

```
root@me:/home/memee/Desktop/test/angular2# npm i -D babel-plugin-angular2-annotations@2.0.1
npm WARN angular2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ babel-plugin-angular2-annotations@2.0.1
added 2 packages from 1 contributor and audited 2145 packages in 58.968s
found 7 vulnerabilities (2 low, 4 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

y como en el error comenta que deberia ejecutar los comandos :

npm  audit fix

y 
`npm audit`

y y cuando corri los dos comandos  intente instarlo de nuevo y me sigue dando el mismo error.

alguna idea? que paso me estoy pasando?

Comment: son warnings, debería instalarlo. el audit y el audit fix es para upgradear packages que se sabe tienen vulnerabilidades

Comment: @aloMalbarez ya no me corre el proyecto :( ajja

Comment: aps hay que leer el audit. Hay algunos upgrades que rompen la compatibilidad aunque solo upgradea si le pones force, en cada audit hay un link al bug y mitigations y esas cosas. ante la duda borrar la carpeta `node_modules` y darle al `npm install` de nuevo.

Comment: como paso extra si no quiere instalar hay q borrar el cache `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @aloMalbarez y si ya no me jala?:( LOL ,dejame limpiarla